# Facing issues while creating build for iOS flutter App

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have created an App using flutter and build is working fine on Android. But while creating iOS build, was getting lots of errors. Rectified many error but still the build is not successful. The error is :

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   : 26 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

The error is appearing while creating app from xCode. The steps for the same are as follows:

1. Imported the Runner.xcworkspace in xCode.
2. Made certificates setting and tried building the code.
3. Got the above error.

While creating app via cmd with the following command:

`flutter build ios -v main_production.dart`

It is showing the following error:

```
Application not configured for iOS

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      BuildIOSCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_ios.dart:62:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:615:18)
#3      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:73:64)
#4      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
#5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
#6      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:139:18)
#7      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:680:45)
#8      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:709:32)
#9      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:524:5)
#10     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:554:7)
#11     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
#12     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#13     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
#14     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
#15     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
#16     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
#17     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#18     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:175:5)
```

Comment: 1) are you tried, flutter doctor -v 2) make sure you are opening workspace

Comment: I have tried building via cmd as well as Android Studio and also using xCode ...

Comment: Flutter doctor gives following output:
Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G103, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 
    • Framework revision 
    • Engine revision e1e6ced81d
    • Dart version 2.7.0